# What are the reasons Oz/Mozart has the reputation of being slow?

Tags: performance, compiler-construction, llvm, oz, mozart

I am aware that it is an academic project, but the Oz/Mozart is such a beautiful language, and I'd love to use it for my pet projects.

Is this reputation deserved? If so:

- is it only the the compiler, or also the execution?
- Are the speed issues at the core of the implementation, or just due to a lack of time spent addressing those speed issues, or else?

Answer (score 3):

> What are the reasons Oz/Mozart has the reputation of being slow?

Maybe, because it is slow?

But this should not stop you from using it. If you like it so much - use it! After all, people use very slow languages all the time. (I mean slow in all aspects - compilation and/or execution)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I expected an answer in the likes of: Mozart is only very slow at compilation due to non-optimized compiler, it's an academic project, and no effort was put in optimizing the compiler. Or the compiler is slow because a lot of set theory is use to make the generated llvm code performant, and the resulting executable is just 40% slower than Haskell, besides concurrent dataflow. Or both are slow because we haven't found a good theory yet to increase performance over so many paradigms in the same language...

Comment: @user957396 I am assembly programmer. From my point of view almost all high level languages are slow. If you wanted to create fast programs you wouldn't like Oz. Therefore, you want to create slow programs, or you don't care about the speed of your programs. But do not worry, you are like 90% of programmers in the world. As I already wrote, the people use very slow languages all the time.

Comment: @user957396 thanks for your comment, maybe I should have formulated the question in another manner: why has it the reputation of being *praticularly*, it is obvious I won't compare high level languages to assembly code. Anyway, I'll probably try to run some benchmarks with existing benchmarking platforms/tools